# How can I randomly do a partial outer join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two single column tables, A and B. I want to create a new table where each element of A is paired with a sample of 3 random elements from B, i.e.:

Table A:

```
A1  
A2  
A3
```

Table B:

```
B1  
B2  
B3  
...  
B100
```

Result Table C:

```
A1 B51  
A1 B63  
A1 B17   
A2 B62    
A2 B13    
A2 B17  
A3 B1  
A3 B69  
A3 B78
```

The values of B are random for each A. Repetition/overlap is fine for different As but not for a given A (i.e. each A must be paired with 3 unique elements of B, but different As can have the same elements from B; that said, it should be highly unlikely for different As to have identical sets of Bs). Is there a way to do this without using a for loop over the elements of A?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: perhaps `FROM A cross apply (Select top 10 FROM B order by random())` but it depends on dbms

Comment: we are using SQL Server

Comment: Version? > 2005?  so wait if A has records 1-5 and B has records A-Z and we return A-J  do you want 1a and 1b  or do you want a to be tied to all 10 records from B (A-J) and 10 different records per A?  In other words.. if A has 5 records do you want your output to be 10 records (5*2 each from B) or (5*10)? AND... do you want A-J each time or every record to be AB or a random sampling from A-J?

Comment: Yes, 2008.  

Needs to be a different set of 10 records for each item

Comment: Sample w/ expected output from B would help clairify question.

Comment: I've updated the question, is it clear now?

Comment: "but different As can have the same elements from B)" .... this makes it much simpler; my answer assumed that you needed unique B items for each A.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest method might be `outer apply`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a outer apply
     (select top 3 b.*
      from b
      where b.id <> a.id   -- just needed to prevent correlation "optimization"
      order by newid()
     ) b;
```

I do emphasize "simple".  For larger `b` tables, Ross's solution is probably faster.

Comment: Again, I think this will duplicate items -- each item of A will get the same items from B.

Comment: @RossPresser . . . That is possible, but only if SQL Server optimizes away the repeated calls to the subquery.  That in turn can be fixed by adding a correlation condition.

Comment: Are you using the id from the table PK or you suggest create a `row_number() id` ? Im worry you cant select from B if same id as A

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . I don't understand your comment.  This answer has no `row_number()`.  It does have a pretty worthless correlation clause that should ensure that the correlated subquery is run multiple times.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I had assumed from the original problem statement that each row from A should get a *completely different* set of rows from B. Later the OP corrected and said that was not the case. Your solution works for the corrected question but not for my original impression of the question.

Comment: @RossPresser . . . I added the correlation clause, because you may have been on to something anyway.  Some databases under some circumstances will "forget" that `newid()` (or the equivalent function) produces a new value each time it is called.  This can result in the subquery only being called once.

Comment: In the question there isnt anything call `id` that is why not sure what are your refering too. And if you are refering to the only column in tableA and tableB you are assuming they dont have any values on common. Otherwise you are limiting the id be part of the random space.

Comment: For some reason the correlation doesnt work for me. The subquery runs only once and returns the same results for each A row.

Comment: We could force the correlation by doing something like `order by newid(), a.id`.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Dont know if this help, but in [**rextester**](http://rextester.com/RNW7588) works ok

Answer (score 0):

This will do it but it's not terribly fast. Assume F1 is the primary key of A (or at least, some unique key of A), and F2 is the value you want from B (primary key or not):

```
WITH X AS (
   SELECT A.F1,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.F1) AS N
   FROM A
), Y AS (
   SELECT B.F2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS N
   FROM B
) 
SELECT A.F1, B.F2
FROM X INNER JOIN Y ON Y.N BETWEEN (X.N-1)*10+1 and ((X.N)*10)
```

EDIT: fix off by one error. Now use Y.N=1..10 for X.N=1, Y.N=11..20 for X.N=2, etc.

Comment: I try to test your function , but doesnt work. Could you check it [here](http://rextester.com/WRMK38236)

Comment: Updated answer. Note your B table only has 15 items so it can't satisfy all 5 A items. (I tried to give an updated test but my changes didn't stick; I'm not terribly familiar with that test site.)

Comment: My answer assumed you needed unique B items for each A. Your updated question clarifies that's not necessary. Two answers that I have "shot down" would satisfy your needs because of this misunderstanding.

Comment: I understand OP need 10 random B for each A row. But one item from B can appear multiple times, The constrain is don't use the same 10 random B for all A.

Comment: Yeah, I interpreted it wrong; it's not as restrictive as I thought it was. Oh well.

Comment: You dont need assume F1 is PK of tableA, just use the N from row_number.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works:

```
    ;
    WITH    RandomBs
              AS ( SELECT c.ClientId AS val
                    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NEWID() ) ) rn
                    FROM Clients c),
            A AS ( SELECT DO.OrganizationId
                    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) rn
                    FROM Organizations DO)
        SELECT *
            FROM A
                CROSS APPLY ( SELECT val
                                FROM RandomBs
                                WHERE rn BETWEEN ( ( ( A.rn - 1 ) * 10 ) + 1 ) AND ( (A.rn * 10) ) ) x
```