# SQL Join doesn't match all elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, random

I was solving this question: [How can I randomly do a partial outer join in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009084/how-can-i-randomly-do-a-partial-outer-join-in-sql/44009462?noredirect=1#comment75048618_44009462) At the end didnt work because can assign multiple times the same row.

But I have a behavior I can't explain where the query doesn't return the expected number of rows

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/QOQU96231)**

```
WITH tableA as (
    SELECT T.id
    FROM ( VALUES (111), (222), (333), (444), (555) ) T(id)
), tableB as (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (order by note) as rn
    FROM ( VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('e'), 
                  ('f'), ('g'), ('h'), ('i'), ('j'),
                  ('k'), ('l'), ('m'), ('n'), ('o') 
         ) T(note)
), parameter as (
    SELECT 3 as row_limit, (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM tableB) as max_limit
), Nums AS (
    SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
    FROM sys.all_objects 
), random_id as (
    SELECT tableA.*, T.n,  floor(p.max_limit * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) + 1 magic_number 
    FROM tableA
    CROSS JOIN parameter p
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT n
                FROM Nums 
                CROSS JOIN parameter p 
                WHERE n <= p.row_limit ) T
)
-- SELECT * FROM random_id
SELECT R.*, note
FROM random_id R
JOIN tableB
  ON R.magic_number = tableB.rn
ORDER BY id
```

1. The setup: `tableA` 5 rows, `tableB` 15 rows. 3 random `tableB` rows for each row in tableA. So in total should return 3 * 5 = 15 rows
2. I create a `row_number()` from 1 to 15 to match to the magic number
3. Create the `random_id` cte to assing three random number to each row of tableA. Here you can see the 15 rows with a random number, also show the problem when assign same value twice

   ```
   SELECT * FROM random_id;
   ```

   [image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/awX6]
4. But the `JOIN` return a random number of rows. more and less than 15

   ```
   SELECT R.*, note
   FROM random_id R
   JOIN tableB
     ON R.magic_number = tableB.rn
   ORDER BY id
   ```

   [image]
5. But if I use `LEFT JOIN` instead always return 15 rows.

**Question:** If `random_id` cte always return 15 rows how `JOIN` return more rows, and how return less if all `rn` values are in the tableB.

And how `LEFT JOIN` always return 15 rows.

I just test another query where I include the `n` value and the JOIN

Comment: [bug with newid() and table expressions (ctes)](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions)

Comment: Here is a similar situation with a great explanation by Paul White: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30348/43889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you would have to persist the rows that are using the `magic_number` to temporary table or other similar construct.

rextester demo here: http://rextester.com/ICS74177

Unfortunately persisting it to a temporary table does result in a loss of elegance of the answer you were attempting. I have run into the same situation in the past trying to do the same thing and encountered the same bug. It's both somewhat exciting and ultimately disappointing when you run into it for the first time, so congrats on that at least!

I can not explain it any better, so **please upvote Paul White's answer**  here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30348/43889

Reference:

- [bug with newid() and table expressions (ctes)](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions)
- [`newid()` In Joined Virtual Table Causes Unintended Cross Apply Behavior - Answer by Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30348/43889)

Comment: Your seem very similar to my bug, the weird part is `LEFT JOIN` seem to be a work around  :/